# Which registers are safe to use in a function (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86, abi

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Intel_ABI) the Intel ABI allows using `EAX`, `ECX` and `EDX` without preserving them in a function.
I am not sure what "Intel ABI" means. Does this mean it is enforced/followed by all compilers targeting Intel CPUs? I am writing an assembly function that will be called from C code. Can I assume this for all compilers? (I am only targeting `x86` at the moment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Intel ABI is just a calling convention established by Intel.

In general, how parameters are passed and which registers are saved or trashed during a function call is defined by the Calling convention of the function:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

In particular for __cdecl, __stdcall and __fastcall you should expect EAX, ECX and EDX to be trashed, and your function should preserve other registers and return on EAX (or EDX:EAX for 64-bit returns).

If you don't know what the calling convention that you should be using is, you shouldn't be writing in assembly, since messing up the calling convention can lead to exploitable bugs in your application.

In C, the default calling convention is normally __cdecl and for Windows exported APIs it is normally __stdcall.

Comment: I know the calling convention I need to be using, and know it's meaning as far as order of parameters and stack cleanup. I didn't know about the registers. Do you know which compilers follow this ABI? msvc/gcc?

Comment: @baruch At least for MSVC, the calling convention is specified in the function prototype. The compiler looks at this and does the right thing. For ex, WSARecv's def starts like this `int WSAAPI WSARecv`. The `WSAAPI` resolves (through several #defines) to __stdcall.

Comment: @MarcSherman I am aware of the calling convention, but is the register preservation part of the calling convention?

Comment: @baruch: Yes. Register preservation is a fundamental part of the calling convention. Read the Wikipedia article in this answer for more details.

Comment: @baruch Sorry about that. Anyhow, the debugger doc that comes with windbg states this about the relationship of calling convention and register preservation: "The x86 architecture has several different calling conventions. Fortunately, they all follow the same register preservation and function return rules"

Answer (score 1):

It's the Intel Application Binary Interface, a set of rules dictating things like what registers are available for use without saving, how arguments are pushed on the stack, whether caller or callee cleans up the stack frames and so on.

If you *know* that the rules are being followed, that's fine. I tend to save everything just in case (other than those things I'm using for returning information of course).

But it's not necessarily enforced for all compilers and you would be unwise to think so unless the compiler specifically states it.